# Show post in table front end

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-table

I want to create a table show all post, I use WP_query to get all iformatio and create table template to list my post. But my problem is only one post inside the table.. I want to include all in table.

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'vendor_management', 'post_status'=>'new', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<table class="responstable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Vendor Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->


    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, I want to create like admin table in backend which is showing all post include edit, delete, bulk delete into front end, Can any body tell me to do it. I have try to use WP_List_Table but not working if in frond end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to be exactly sure about your problem, maybe a live example may help. Also, do you have a custom post status "new" or its a typo?

but looking at the code, I see you have begun the table code outside the while loop, which is correct but ended it inside the loop. This might be the reason for only displaying 1 post. Please find the modified code.

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'vendor_management', 'post_status'=>'new', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<table class="responstable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Vendor Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
     </tbody>
        </table>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your issue I think this function will be working fine for you.Do check it and let me know if you face any issues into it.

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'vendor_management', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<table class="responstable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Vendor Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
     </tbody>
        </table>
    <!-- end of the loop -->


<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```